# SSH asks for key password but it has none

Tags: macos, ssh, keychain

Trying to connect to my server using

```
ssh -l root -i private.key server.com
```

**The key is a Ed25519 in openssh format and has no password set.**

When I enter the above command, OSX keychain asks me for a password. It does not accept my usual system password.

**Why is it asking me for a private key password althogh I have not set one?**

Using `-vvv` I got the message of the file format beeing invalid, well, case closed ^^

```
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: key.priv
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Saving password to keychain failed
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug2: no passphrase given, try next key
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: post verbose log from `ssh -vvv -l root -i private.key server.com` or at least exact error you got.

Comment: @Jakuje I think my private key is simply in the wrong format, thanks for your hint

Comment: If you would post the whole log, I might be more helpful, but my guess is that you have old openssh version and therefore it does not know this format. I would go for updating. Also posting the actual header or "encapsulation boundaries (EB)" should put some light into the problem, but from description I believe they are `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` and you just need to update openssh.